# Problem installing pip in python due to ipykernel

Tags: python, pip, directory, kernel

I am trying to install pip in python which I have saved in the appropriate directory, but when getting python to look for it in the right place, this ipykernel problem keeps happening. This is the error I'm getting when I check the directory is correct and then try to install pip:

```
In [26]: os.getcwd()
Out[26]: 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39'  #correct directory

In [27:] python get-pip.py
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23372\956420117.py", line 1 #incorrect directory
    python get-pip.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even though the current directory is where the file "get-pip" is saved, when I go to install, it keeps looking in the Temp folder and hence cannot find it. Why is it doing this?

Thanks for any help available!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: You are getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, not a `FileNotFoundError`.